# Why does a non-inferiority design require a smaller sample size than a superiority design?

Tags: experiment-design, non-inferiority

I understand that theoretically, because a non-inferiority design has a wider range of successful outcomes (equivalence *or* superiority) vs. a superiority design which only has one successful outcome, then it should require a smaller sample size.

But I really can't wrap my head around how this affects a power analysis. At the end of the day, aren't I just trying to find a sample size that can detect an *x*% difference between two study populations? Why should the design of my trial affect how many subjects are needed to detect that difference?

Comment: Isn't it simply because a superiority trail tests two-sided and a non-inferiority trial one-sided?

Comment: Why does a superiority trial need to test two-sided?

Comment: Because despite what the name suggests, it is called a superiority test is when you test for *a difference*.